# Changing the appearance of circles on mouseover and mouseout (with transitions)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a line plot with some circle markers.

[image]

I'd like to add some mouseover and mouseout effects to the circles.

Here is my code:

```
let linePlot = svg.selectAll('.line')
    .data(data);

// Draws the line
linePlot
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .merge(linePlot)
    .datum(data)
    .transition()
    .duration(800)
    .attr('class', 'line')
    .attr('d', d3.line()
        .x(function (d) { return xScale(d.YEAR); })
        .y(function (d) { return yScale(d[metricType]); })
        .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
    );

linePlot
    .exit()
    .remove();

// Draws the circles
let circles = svg.selectAll('circle')
    .data(data);

circles
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .merge(circles)
    .data(data)
    .transition()
    .duration(800)
    .attr('fill', '#5e855d')
    .attr('stroke', '#49614a')
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return xScale(d.YEAR)})
    .attr('cy', function(d) { return yScale(d[metricType])})
    .attr('r', 6)
;

circles
    .on('mouseover', function() {
        d3.select(this)
            .transition()
            .duration(2000)
            .attr('fill', 'red')
    })
    .on('mouseout', function() {
        d3.select(this)
            .transition()
            .duration(2000)
            .attr('fill', 'blue')
    })

circles
    .exit()
    .remove();
```

The mouseout and mouseover effects are not working.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you do this...

```
circles
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .merge(circles)
    .data(data)
    .transition()
    .duration(800)
    .attr('fill', etc...
```

...you're basically setting `circles` as a *transition selection*, and transitions don't have `mouseover` as a typename. The only typenames allowed for a transition are:

- `start`
- `end`
- `interrupt`
- `cancel`

The idiomatic solution is breaking that chain:

```
circles.enter()
    .append('circle')
    .merge(circles)
    .data(data);

circles.transition()
    .duration(800)
    .attr('fill', etc...
```

Now `circles` is a proper D3 selection, so you can do `circles.on('mouseover', etc...`.

Finally, consider revising that `data` method after merging, it makes little sense to me.